# Posting text string to server side text file using Action Script 3

Tags: php, actionscript

I'm trying to modify the [Storm Flash MP3](http://activeden.net/item/storm-mp3-player/115546?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=AerisT) player to record the artist name and title of a played/unplayed song.  The author updated the player to skip a song if there is an IO Error.
I found the code below and it works for songs that played. For some reason, when I add it to the IOError function, it doesn't work at all.

I am a novice when it comes to Flash.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Record Played Song Info via PHP script
    scriptVars.var1 = "1+" + String(aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][1] + "+" + aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][2]);
    scriptVars.var2 = (scriptDate);
    scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;
    scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
//End of Record Played Song Info via PHP script
```

**Play Function**

```
function playMP3():void {
    tMP3Transform.volume = nCurrVolume;
    schMP3 = sMP3.play();
    schMP3.soundTransform = tMP3Transform;
    **//Record Played Song Info via PHP script
    scriptVars.var1 = "1+" + String(aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][1] + "+" + aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][2]);
    scriptVars.var2 = (scriptDate);
    scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;
    scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
        //End of Record Played Song Info via PHP script**
    if(mcStormHolder.mcPlayBtn.currentFrame >= 20) {
    schMP3.stop();
}
        schMP3.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, incrementTrack, false, 0, true);

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateViz);
    bForceRandom = false;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateViz, false, 0, true);
}
```

**IOERROR Function**

```
function onMP3IOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("An IO error occurred while attempting to load the MP3 track.");
    //sMP3.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onMP3Loaded);
    sMP3.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onMP3IOError);
    sMP3.removeEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onMP3SecurityError);
    //incrementTrack();
    mcStormHolder.mcInfoBar.txInfo.text = String(aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][1] + " - " + aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][2]);
    mcStormHolder.mcInfoBar.txInfo.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    mcStormHolder.mcInfoBar.txInfo.x = 50;
    //Record Song if for songs that did not play
    scriptVars.var1 = "0+" + String(aMP3Tracks[iCurrTrack][0]);
    scriptVars.var2 = (scriptDate);
    scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;
    scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
    //Record Song if for songs that did not play

    //Begin Modification for Roger Stull - Skip song if will not load
    abortLoad();
    bForceRandom = false;
    if (schMP3 != null) {
        schMP3.stop();
    schMP3.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, incrementTrack);
    nPausePos = 0;

    iCurrTrack = iCurrTrack + 1;
    if(iCurrTrack > iNumTracks-1){
        iCurrTrack = 0;
    }
    sMP3 = new Sound();
    schMP3 = new SoundChannel();
    loadMP3();
}
//End Modification for Roger Stull
}
```

Comment: Does the IOError function get called?